# Facebook, Object Debugger, problems (Parsed as type 'url' & Error Parsing Input URL)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Placed in the `<head>`

```
<title>Adasa Photographic Art</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Adasa Photographic Art"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="company"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.adasaphotographicart.com/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.adasaphotographicart.com/pictures/Arizona/(5)051113144-copy.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.adasaphotographicart.com/pictures/Arizona/(9)DSC_1003-copy.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.adasaphotographicart.com/pictures/Animal/(7)05070511.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.adasaphotographicart.com/pictures/Animal/(12)07260608.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.adasaphotographicart.com/pictures/Utah/(2)_D209741-(2).jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.adasaphotographicart.com/pictures/California/(1)_D207594.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.adasaphotographicart.com/pictures/Utah/(23)DSC_64191.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Landscape Photography"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="283571581734665"/>
<meta property="og:description"
          content="Photography at its best, from California to Texas and many places in between. Click and see what we have to offer."/>
```

Placed in the `<body>`

```
<div id="fb-local">
        <span><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FAdasaPhotographicArt&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </span></div>
```

I'm trying to place a like button on my site. When I put this code, which has been edited and regenerate multiple times in accordance of the recommendations of multiple sites it continues to have the same problem. The button shows up (Not in the correct spot but thats CSS I know) but the button doesn't work and when I try to Debug with the Facebook Dev. Tool it gives me multiple errors. When using this config. I get...

```
Error Parsing URL:  Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.
```

I've gotten a little further in other configurations.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="adasaphotographicart.com/"/>
```

I get

```
Object at URL 'http://adasaphotographicart.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 'adasaphotographicart.com/' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.
```

P.s I have __ at the top of the source code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: Removed the text o.0 how does this now help others?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I get

`<meta property="og:type" content="website">`

`<meta property="og:url" content="adasaphotographicart.com/">`

as your Open Grab tags.

The og:url requires the http:// at the start and that should fix that.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adasaphotographicart.com%2F

As you are liking the Root page of your website, you need og:type website

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

> Use article for any URL that represents transient content - such as a
>   news article, blog post, photo, video, etc. Do not use website for
>   this purpose. website and blog are designed to represent an entire
>   site, an og:type tag with types website or blog should usually only
>   appear on the root of a domain.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, I forgot to put it back to its original when I was testing to send you guys two different scenarios, Type set to website and the url set to http://adasaphotographicart.com

Comment: All looks good currently: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fadasaphotographicart.com%2F